How to highlight files and changes that are not pushed yet, but commited
I love how IntelliJ Idea makes files with uncommitted changes blue, but sometimes I really miss seeing them that way after having to commit for some reason (for example, to change to different branch). Can I make IntelliJ Idea still show files that have local changes that aren't pushed yet, even if committed still with different color? Can I still see the non-pushed changed lines after commit? It would help me big way!
I tried searching in Options but haven't really succeeded.

Don't know if IntelliJ lets you reach it but Git does that with git diff @{u} @.
